# get $tempstore inside a twig file drupal 8

Tags: twig, drupal-8

i'm creating a module my_module, I want to tempstore a variable and get it inside a twig file.
here my controller:

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule');
            $tempstore->set('response', $response);
```

twig:

```
{{ ?? like response }}
```

Comment: Pass `$tempstore` to the template?

Answer (score 1):

First register your theme in module file

```
function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'my_template' => [
      'variables' => ['test_var' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Second call this theme from controller and pass the variable

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule');
            $tempstore->set('response', $response);
return [
      '#theme' => 'my_template',
      '#test_var' => $tempstore,
    ];
```

Third render test_var in twig

```
<p>test_var: {{ test_var }}</p>
```