# Access variable in Twig template of custom module Drupal 8

Tags: php, symfony, module, twig, drupal-8

I want to use a variable in the Twig file of Drupal 8. And that twig variable should be available for all pages of the site.

Suppose I have a variable `$my_variable` created in my Form or in Controller. so now I want to use this `$my_variable` in my twig file.

```
Like this {{ my_variable }}.
```

I have already tried this approach :

[get $tempstore inside a twig file drupal 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040567/get-tempstore-inside-a-twig-file-drupal-8)

My Module file:

```php
function my_module_theme() {
    return [
        'theme_tag' => [
        'variables' => ['my_variable' => NULL],
        ],
    ];
}
```

My Controller :

```
public function callMe() {
     $my_variable= "some data here";
     return [
          '#theme' => 'theme_tag',
          '#my_variable' => $my_variable,
     ];
}
```

My Twig :

```
<p> {{ my_variable}} </p>
```

any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this question should be on: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @felipsmartins, please find the solution and share the exact link not a link to the whole site.

Comment: @Nasser actually, this question is a little bit of off-topic, cause there's a specific channel for drupal+twig related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **A complete test module with template created on git hub you can check that as well.
>   https://github.com/nassernak/drupal8-custom-template**

You need to define the path of twig template

```
'path' => $path . '/templates',
'template' => 'twig-template-file-name',
```

`$path` -> refer to you module directory

`templates` ->is a folder that contains your templates

`template` -> just the file name without extension, in my case without `.html.twig`.

---

Totally, define your theme hook like this and set your variable in variables array.

```
   function your_module_name_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return [
        'theme_tag' => [
          'variables' => [
            'var2' => NULL,
            'var2' => NULL,
          ],
          'path' => $path . '/templates',
          'template' => 'twig-template-file-name-without-extention',
        ],
      ];
    }
```

Then in your callback function that will refer to your template use this sample.

```
public function basePageCallback() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'theme_tag',
      '#var1' => 'test',
      '#var2' => 'test2',
    ];
```

And then access it on your twig
`{{var1}}`

Comment: Hi [@Nasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9246297/nasser) thanks but this is not working for me. could you please suggest me any other way.

Comment: I use this in a real project and working fine for me, So what error do you have? can you clarify?

Comment: [@Nasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9246297/nasser) there is no error, actually, I just print that ```{{ variable }}``` in my twig file to ensure that have I got the value perfectly or not. so value is not get printed on page this means value does not come in. I have sent you an mail on your mail address(nak.73406@gmail.com) when you will get time please look at that. Thanks!

Comment: @Ankit what about the cache? Did you clear cache, as you should know cache in Drupal is very tricky and many times need to clear to see the correct result?

Comment: @Ankit I create a simple test module to show you the process, you can check it on Github https://github.com/nassernak/drupal8-custom-template , I hope this help you and some others

Comment: Thank you so much [@Nasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9246297/nasser). it's working perfectly fine. this demo is very useful for me and will be for others also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create the twig file in `mymodulename/templates/my-template-name.html.twig`

```
<div>{{ my_variable }}</div>
```

Then add `hook_theme` in `mymodulename.module`:

```
function mymodulename_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'my_template_name' => [
      'variables' => [
        'my_variable' => 'default value',
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Call template:

```
  // Call the mail template
  $template = [
    '#theme' => 'my_template_name',
    '#my_variable' => 'my variable value',
  ];
  // Render the template
  $rendered_template = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($template);

  return ['#markup' => $rendered_template];
```

Comment: I don't remember if you have to render the template... try to return `$template` directly

Comment: Sorry @STF but still not working. if I use this approach in theme it is perfectly working fine, but when I try to do this in my custom Module it is not working. and my twig template is loading I'm sure about it. I have used predefined variable `{{ url('<current>') }}` to confirm twig is loading or not. and I get the current URL print on-page.